# Python Web Scraping a site-Output to Excel

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to programming this question can be mundane to the very experienced ones but kindly assist. I would like to crawl a site(recently found out you can get data that way)to get data extract the data to Excel for analysis. The website has a very standard structure, it's a betting site, so date, teams, leagues odds all very structured, I would want to have scrappy go through this data and provide a response in Excel, CSV file which I shall run a coded Excel program for analysis.
Someone introduced me to learning Python of which I am doing and would want to use this as a practise run in my learning. The book I am reading Introducing Python by Bill Lubanovic lead me to scrapp.org and from scrappy to here.

Thank you in advance
Kapitan
P/S In your reply, kindly respond as if it's to a new programmer of which I am trying to be.

Comment: StackOverflow is not an advice forum or a code writing forum. What have you tried so far? Show your work so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the scrappy tutorials found [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). If you don't understand the things mentioned there, you should improve your Python skills first. [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) is a good starting point for doing so.

Comment: Thanks, will go through Python and do a code for you review